# Transitioning to view programmatically ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a view that carries out a task, when the task is completed the activity indicator will become hidden, I want to send the user to another view when the activity is completed, or give  the user an error if unsuccessful. So far I am using an If Else statement to give a success alert or an error alert. There is no buttons to click or anything, simply after the activity is completed the user will be sent to another view passing a few variables along the way.

How would I go about sending the user to another view after completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it working, along with passing a variable to the other view using this method:

```
DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView"];
[detail setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
detail.videoURL = outputURL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a navigationcontroller:

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:theNextViewController animated:YES];
```

For Storyboard, look up the method in the docu.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on AlexWien's answer a little...

- Create a view controller or table view controller class that you want
  the user to go to after completion.
- Create some properties for the data you want to pass in.

---

```
@protocol UpdatePricesDelegate;

@interface NXUpdatePricesViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic)   NSArray *calculationProducts;
@property (strong, nonatomic)   NSArray *filteredCalculationProducts;

@property (weak, nonatomic)     id<UpdatePricesDelegate>delegate;

@end

@protocol UpdatePricesDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)updatePricesController:(NXUpdatePricesViewController *)controller didUpdateCalculationProducts:(NSArray *)calculationProducts;

@end
```

---

- When you are ready to display your controller (presumably in your If/Else statement), instantiate the class (don't forget #import "MyClassName.h") and set the properties to the variables you want to pass.
- Present the class modally (example includes a navigation controller), or if you want to push the view, use your navigation controller.

---

```
NXUpdatePricesViewController *updatePricesController = [[NXUpdatePricesViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
updatePricesController.delegate = self;
updatePricesController.calculationProducts = self.calculationProducts;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:updatePricesController];
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;


[self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

```
NXCalculationViewController *calculationController = [[NXCalculationViewController alloc] init];
calculationController.calculation = calculation;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:calculationController animated:YES];
```